# ¿ Como obtener el nombre de los encabezados de una tabla de Mysql y hacer esa consulta en java?

Tags: sql

estoy buscando como listar el nombre de los encabezados de una tabla Mysql en un JTable de java , lo he hecho pero con un DefaultTableModel , Modelo.addColumn("Nombrecolumna"), estoy funciona para una sola tabla , pero no todas las tablas tiene las misma cantidad de columnas , y agregar manualmente los encabezados , no es muy dinámico , por eso me gustaría saber como imprimir los nombres de los encabezados de un tabla Mysql en java . Y esa consulta luego , poder pasarla a los encabeados de un JTable con JTableHeader.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que acceder a la base information_schema dentro de MySQL y hacer una consulta filtrando por la base y tabla que buscas:
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM columns WHERE TABLE_NAME="nombre_table" AND TABLE_SCHEMA ="nombre_base"